# Interceptor not getting called when zuul.routes configured in gateway

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

When I configure zuul routes in bootstrap.properties, my **TestHandlerInterceptor** defined in gareway application is not getting invoked for all the request matching **/registrations** but it gets called for all other request  TestHandlerInterceptor.preHandle  is getting processed successfully

*bootstrap.properties*

```
zuul.routes.registration-service.path=**registrations**
zuul.routes.registration-service.service=registration-service
```

TestHandlerInterceptor.java

```
public class TestHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {


 @Autowired
 AuthenticationService authenticationService;


 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(" ********* preHandle ********");
    boolean result = true;
    if(!authenticationService.isAuthenticated(httpServletRequest)){
        result = false;
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(401);
    }


    return result;
 }

 @Override
 public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

 }

 @Override
 public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Object o, Exception e) throws Exception {

}
 }
```

GatewayApplication.java

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class GatewayApplication{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
 }

 @Bean
 public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new TestHandlerInterceptor());
            super.addInterceptors(registry);
        }
    };
 }
}


@RestController
class Orchestration {
 @LoadBalanced
 @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate ;

 @RequestMapping("/api/test")
 public @ResponseBody
 Collection<Registration> getRegistrations(){
   ResponseEntity<Resources<Client>> resourceResponseEntity =  this.restTemplate.exchange("http://registration-service/registrations", HttpMethod.GET,null, ptr);

 }

}
```

The TestHandlerInterceptor.preHandle executes for localhost:1122/api/test but its not getting called for localhost:1122/registrations

I am trying to add a AuthenticationService in my interceptor which will perform all stateless Authentication(using api keys) before any of the sub resource is requested.

I tried ZuulFilter implementation and the MyZuulFilter.run()  is call for all the localhost:1122/registrations request but not for localhost:1122/api/test

How can I configure the interceptor in a way that its gets executed before anything else

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Angel.SR6</version>
</parent>
```

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 2):

look at this.
[HandlerInterceptorAdapter and Zuul Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801282/handlerinterceptoradapter-and-zuul-filter)

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ZuulHandlerBeanPostProcessor extends InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter {

    private MyInterceptor myInterceptor = new MyInterceptor();

    @Override
    public boolean postProcessAfterInstantiation(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof ZuulHandlerMapping) {
             ZuulHandlerMapping zuulHandlerMapping = (ZuulHandlerMapping) bean;
             Object[] objects = {oauth2Interceptor};
            zuulHandlerMapping.setInterceptors(objects);
        }
        return super.postProcessAfterInstantiation(bean, beanName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying  WebMvcconfigurator bean as below

```
@Bean
 public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new TestHandlerInterceptor( ()).addPathPatterns("/**")
        }
    };
 }
}
```

Also change the bootstrap properties to:-

```
zuul.routes.registration-service.path=/registrations/**
zuul.routes.registration-service.service=registration-service
```

Comment: Adding addPathPatterns("/**") didn't gave expected result.. may be i am doing something wrong

Comment: updated the answer maybe you need to change the path pattern. Are you able to hit the registration service via zuul.

Comment: Already have  zuul.routes.registration-service.path=**registrations**
zuul.routes.registration-service.service=registration-service in bootstrap. I am able to hit the service via zuul, but  my interceptor is not getting called. For now I have repeated my Authentication(using api keys)  code in ZuulFilter.run().    Now the code exists in two place Filter and Interceptor which I am trying to avoide