# HandlerInterceptorAdapter and Zuul Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

It is possible add a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` with *Zuul* Configuration. I need to intercept a request to a specific resource but I suppose because I have *Zuul* filter configuration, the interceptor is never called.

Is possible to do so?

Comment: some punctuation and formatting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have tried to achieve the same. We have a few Spring MVC controllers and Zuul proxying. But I still wanted the same Interceptor to be used.

The problem here is that zuul runs in its own ZuulServlet, and does not pick up the interceptors from your MVC servlet. [Spring Cloud: ZuulConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/zuul/ZuulConfiguration.java) configures ZuulHandlerMapping, which is the only place interceptors could be set, but it's not configurable. Thus you need a `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter` to interfere with the bean creation, to set your interceptors after instantiaton, but before initialization (before the interceptors are initialized).

This did the trick for me:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ZuulHandlerBeanPostProcessor extends InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter {

    @NonNull
    private final MyInterceptor myInterceptor;

    @Override
    public boolean postProcessAfterInstantiation(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {

        if (bean instanceof ZuulHandlerMapping) {

            val zuulHandlerMapping = (ZuulHandlerMapping) bean;
            zuulHandlerMapping.setInterceptors(myInterceptor);
        }

        return super.postProcessAfterInstantiation(bean, beanName);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot my lifesaver! +1 for you.