# Add a interceptor in spring cloud zuul version 1.1.0M4

Tags: java, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to intercept a every request in zuul, I tried to follow [Interceptor not getting called when zuul.routes configured in gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553487/interceptor-not-getting-called-when-zuul-routes-configured-in-gateway) link but in this case they are using WebMvcCounfigurerAdapter but I am not being able to use it since my application is not mvc application. Can we have some other approach to so that.

Comment: Use can use a "pre" ZuulFilter

Comment: @Hemant pre filter will do for once if I need to intercept every request pre-filter won't work

Comment: Pre filter will be called for each request, not once only

Comment: Can u explain what u want to do after intercepting the request

Comment: @HemantPatel sorry for the late reply. I have done that with Pre filter earlier but while deployment i was having issue with artifact. So thought of implementing the interceptor but later on the problem rectified and the pre filter started working. Thank you very much